# How can I make the menubutton in tkinter perform specific function when clicked

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, tkinter

I copied this code though

```
from Tkinter import * import tkMessageBox import Tkinter

top = Tk()

mb= Menubutton ( top, text="condiments", relief=RAISED ) mb.grid() mb.menu = Menu ( mb, tearoff = 0 ) mb["menu"] = mb.menu

mayoVar = IntVar() ketchVar = IntVar()

mb.menu.add_checkbutton ( label="mayo", variable=mayoVar ) mb.menu.add_checkbutton ( label="ketchup", variable=ketchVar )

mb.pack() top.mainloop()
```

When someone clicks on mayo..i want it to perform a specific function

Answer (score 2):

Use a callback function to implement what you want done and then call it from the menu item:

```
def callback_function():
    # Your code here

mb.menu.add_checkbutton(label="mayo", variable=mayoVar,
                        command=callback_function)
```

To get information about the state of a checkbutton you need to save the state to a variable. Here is an examle of how you can do it by creating a dict which saves tha variable under the button name:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('300x200')

def show_name_details(name):
    print(f'show_name_details: {name}, is {name_dict[name].get()}')

mb = tk.Menubutton(root, text="condiments", relief='raised')
mb.grid()
mb.menu = tk.Menu(mb, tearoff=0)
mb["menu"] = mb.menu

name_dict = {'Mayo': tk.IntVar(), 'Ketchup': tk.IntVar()}
for name, var in name_dict.items():
    mb.menu.add_checkbutton(label=name, variable=name_dict[name],
                            command=lambda n=name:show_name_details(n))

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hello, 
Can we dynamically add more check buttons to menu and pass different strings to one function?
I have tried to pass, but it shows only the last variable in it.

for name in name_dict.keys():
    mb.menu.add_checkbutton(label=name, variable=name, command=show_name_details)

Comment: This is a common issue. The variable `name` will keep the last value assigned to it in the for loop. To keep the value as assigned **during** the loop you can use a lambda with a default value: `command=lambda n=name:show_name_details(n)`.

Comment: Hello @figbeam
What if I want to send the information whether the item is selected or not, for that how the check button will be?

Comment: Added new explanation of that.